# How to remove keyboard flicker when switching between TextFields?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, android-compose-textfield

I have a LazyColumn consisting of text fields with numeric input. When I switch between text fields, I sometimes see a flicker. It first opens the normal text keyboard and then switches to numeric one. This is leading to a really bad UX.

My code:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    items(payers) {
        Row {
            Image(...)
            Text(...)
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                    .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
            ) {
                BasicTextField(
                    value = it.amount,
                    onValueChange = { /* Update it.amount */ },
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                )
                if (it.amount.isEmpty())
                    Text(
                        text = "₹ 0",
                        modifier = Modifier.alpha(0.5f)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

How to avoid this flicker?

Comment: Yeah actually I'm very sleepy at the moment so for now, just try, instead of using default KeyBoardType.Number, try configuring it to allow only a set of digits, something like "12345667890."

Comment: I don't want to show alphabets to user and then restrict them from typing those

Comment: How to "allow" certain characters in Compose Text Field? Don't say "filter those out when onValueChange is triggered". I don't think that is gonna change keyboard type

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a known bug (specifically, that the keyboard type changes very quickly during focus request).

You can follow along [on the bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/187746439) for updates.